# Error with tidyr when converting rows to columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to convert rows into columns to return the average cost of each mode. I am trying to use the pivot_wider function but it gives the following error.
Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`.

I tried updating the package but still the problem persists. Any other alternative to get the desired result other than pivot_wider?
My dataframe `prcostdata`looks like this.

```
S447.1               cost
Car                  100
Government Ambulance 50
Jeep                 600
Scooter              800
Government Ambulance 100
Car                  200
Jeep                 1500
Scooter              750
```

Desired output.

```
Government Ambulance  Car  Jeep  Scooter
75                    150  1050  775
```

Here is my code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
trans <- c("Government Ambulance","Car","Jeep","Scooter")
prcostmode<-prcostdata %>% 
  arrange(match(S447.1, trans)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = S447.1, values_from = mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr` like this

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="S447.1", values_from="cost", values_fn=mean)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 4
    Car Government_Ambulance  Jeep Scooter
  <dbl>                <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1   150                   75  1050     775
```

---

### Data

```r
structure(list(S447.1 = c("Car", "Government_Ambulance", "Jeep", 
"Scooter", "Government_Ambulance", "Car", "Jeep", "Scooter"), 
    cost = c(100, 50, 600, 800, 100, 200, 1500, 750)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(S447.1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), cost = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Comment: What version of `tidyr` are you using? Perhaps you have to update your package.

Answer (score 1):

Data.table solution:

```
setDT(df)
dcast(df, .~S447.1, fun = mean, value.var = "cost")
```

Comment: Nice one, but `sum` should be `mean`.